# MainService vs. Application

Tags: android

My conceptual question circles around Android. What I like to do is running a service that acts as the central point for application-wide things and combine this with an event-system. For instance, when a user clicks a button that causes IO, this button dispatches an event (Broadcast, Intent, greenrobot.EventBus, whatever), the MainService then receives the event and kicks off, for instance, an IntentService. Once the IntentService is finished, I again dispatch an Event back to the MainService and so forth.

This works very nice for me, it splits the concerns and I have no clutter in my Activities/Fragments, it helps me organize things.

But I am not sure if I really need that MainService, at least for this particular case. I extend Application anyway and registering a BroadcastReceiver or EventBus is no problem at all. Should I get rid of the MainService?

Answer (score 1):

Application object is not responsible for delegating events to different part of the app. I would suggest not to clutter it with such responsibilities.

From what I understand, your `MainService` class is some sort of dispatcher that initiates some service or activity when it gets a particular event. This should be a separate class as you have designed. I would suggest to change its name if possible as `MainService` does not give proper idea about what it really does. You could call it something like `EventDispatcherService` or `CentralEventHandlingService` etc.